# How to use the "post" parameter with the Excel's 2003 hyperlink "follow(...)" method?

Tags: excel, vba, post, hyperlink

If you look at Excel's help for the `Follow` method of the `Hyperlink` object, you'll see that it accepts POST as a way to send the data. How should I fill the `Extra Info` string or byte array? How should I format the data? What is the limit for the data to be sent? Please see below:

**expression.Follow(NewWindow, AddHistory, ExtraInfo, Method, HeaderInfo)**

**Method**    Optional Variant. Specifies the way `ExtraInfo` is attached. Can be one of the following `MsoExtraInfoMethod` constants.

**ExtraInfo** to specify the coordinates of an image map, the contents of a form, or a FAT file name.

**Method**    Optional Variant. Specifies the way `ExtraInfo` is attached. Can be one of the following `MsoExtraInfoMethod` constants

- **msoMethodGet** `ExtraInfo` is a String that’s appended to the address.
- **msoMethodPost** `ExtraInfo` is posted as a String or byte array.

Answer (score 1):

If you are `GET`ting, you format it as string.

```
Follow(,,,msoMethodGet,"/questions/3354606/")
```

So if the link was `www.stackoverflow.com`, you would go to `www.stackoverflow.com/questions/3354606/`

If you are `POST`ing, you can either use a string OR byte array. You can try something like

```
username=asdf
```

or

```
Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Chr(10) + Chr(13) + username=asdf
```

You may need to look up the spec for HTTP posts and send the entire header.

Comment: Thank you, bugtussle. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it went!